# Unable to link CCfits example program

Tags: c++, linker-errors, fits

This is probably related to

[c++ reading fits file using ccfits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22820019/c-reading-fits-file-using-ccfits)

which was never answered.

Anyway, I hope my question is easier to reproduce.  There is an example program for CCfits at:

http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/fitsio/CCfits/html/cookbook.html

I am attempting to compile this using:

```
g++ cookbook.cpp -o cookbook -lCCfits -lcfitsio
```

The link fails for every CCfits function in the file:

> /tmp/cc7hVaju.o: In function `main':
>   cookbook.cpp:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to`writeImage()'
>   cookbook.cpp:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `writeAscii()'
>   cookbook.cpp:(.text+0x4e): undefined reference to`writeBinary()'
>   cookbook.cpp:(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `copyHDU()'
>   cookbook.cpp:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to`readHeader()'
>   cookbook.cpp:(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to `readImage()'
>   cookbook.cpp:(.text+0xc2): undefined reference to`readTable()'
>   cookbook.cpp:(.text+0xdf): undefined reference to `readExtendedSyntax()'
>   cookbook.cpp:(.text+0xfc): undefined reference to`selectRows()'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I have tried this with the CCfits package that comes with Ubuntu.  I have also tried installing the package myself.  Same error.

Strangely, I get similar messages if I do not include the libraries on the command line (i.e., "g++ cookbook.cpp -o cookbook").  The one difference is that I also get this error:

> /tmp/ccMVMkSB.o: In function `CCfits::FITS::setVerboseMode(bool)':
>   cookbook.cpp:(.text._ZN6CCfits4FITS14setVerboseModeEb[_ZN6CCfits4FITS14setVerboseModeEb]+0xf): undefined reference to`CCfits::FITS::s_verboseMode'

This must be a clue, right?  Seems to say that the libraries I have named, although they exist, do not contain all the functions I need.

Thanks for any help,

Charles

Comment: Wow, that documentation is pretty bad.

Comment: If you have the sources, use `find` with `grep` to search the source files for the undefined references.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas.  Great idea.  Turns out the "cookbook" program referred to in my link above was an incomplete program, the rest of which I found in the source code :-/.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got a suitable answer to this question but as far as I can tell the main issue is that you are not including the definitions to the function signatures.  These are usually defined in the header files of c++ libraries.

For example, if your library is installed in "**/usr/local**" on a UNIX system then the header files will be installed in the location "**/usr/local/include/CCfits**".  The corresponding lib files will be installed at "**/usr/local/lib**".  The important thing is that the compiler does not know this and you need to inform it of these locations.

```
g++ cookbook.cpp -o cookbook -I /usr/local/include/CCfits -L /usr/local/lib -lCCfits -lcfitsio
```

The "**-I /usr/local/include/CCfits**" flag and the given parameter inform g++ of the location of the header files that it is looking for.  The "**-L /usr/local/lib**" flag and the given parameter inform g++ of the location of the library files.  It is important to note that g++ will search in the standard location for libraries on in your environment as well this is just giving it more locations to search.  There are in fact rules for what it should do if it finds multiple libraries which are the same in different locations but I don't explicitly remember those.

Also to be safe, ensure that the libraries are loaded into memory by the OS.  These are shared libraries not static so they are not stored into the executable file.  This won't make a difference when compiling the source but will prevent the successful execution of the executable.  To ensure that the OS has loaded the library into memory run the following command:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Yours Aye,

Omar EQ